# What is the probability of monotonically increasing outcome ratios in repeated Bernoulli trials?

Tags: probability

Suppose that we conduct $nk$ independent Bernoulli trials, and suppose that we divide them into groups of size k, say $G_1, G_2, ..., G_n$. Denote by $r_i$ the ratio of successes to failures. What is the probability that $$r_i \ge r_{i-1}$$ for all $i$ between 2 and $n$? That is, what is the probability that the $r_i$ are monotonically increasing?

As background, it is common to see an experimental design, where some parameter has been varied in a known monotonically increasing way across groups. For example, if we were testing a new type of drug we might divide a population of rats into 4 groups and administer increasing doses of none, 1mg, 2mg to 3mg. Having done this, if we find at the end that the survival rate of the rats after 1 week was .01, .1, .3, .5 we might be inclined to think the drug was efficacious. But was it really? Or are we just correlating the pattern of monotonic input to monotonic output. I'm looking to quantify that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approximate answer. Instead of Bernoulli trials, suppose we have uniform random variables $X$ and $Y$ on the unit interval. Then what is $$Pr( X \le Y)$$

The sample space is the unit square and the upper half is the space of positive outcomes, so the probability is .5.

Similarly, if we have three uniform random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ on the unit interval, the volume of the space defined by the intersection of $$x \le y \le z$$ with the unit cube is equal to $$Pr( X \le Y \le Z)$$

By symmetry arguments, it looks like that area is $1/6$, or $1/3!$. Since there are $3!$ ways to arrange x,y, and z in the inequality, and they are mutually exclusive they must divide the cube into equal parts.

By the same argument then, for $n$ uniform r.v. on the unit interval, the probability $$Pr(X_i \le X_{i+1})$$ for all i is $1/n!$

If f is any p.d.f without point mass, then since it is a map to the interval [0,1] I think the same argument applies.

So a partial answer to the question would be, as k goes to infinity, the probability is $1/n!$.

In the case of small k, for example k = 2 and n = 2, clearly the approximation is not so good (the probability of getting at least one head is 3/4, not 1/2). To get a better handle on the problem we need to compute the probability $$Pr(X = Y)$$ where X and Y Bernoulli r.v. on k trials with probability p of success

$$\sum_{i=0}^k  (\binom{k}{i} p^{i} (1-p)^{k-i})^2 $$